# How can I put a header in my fixed navigation?

Tags: html, css, header, navigation, fixed

I've ran into a problem that I'm not sure how to fixed and I believe it may have to do with the position? I've tried to look up solutions but still can't figure out why this is happening.

So I am trying to put my header (name) in my fixed navigation bar. When I attempt to do this, the header is sitting behind the grey background colour...
How can I bring the header to be on top of the background? I want the header to be fixed with the navigation bar.. thanks so much in advance!

```css
html {
    margin: 0;
    background: #ffffff;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #ffffff;
}

/*---font---*/
@font-face {
    font-family: open-sans;
    src: url('open-sans.regular.ttf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Prata-Regular;
    src: url('Prata-Regular.ttf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Frontage-Outline;
    src: url('Frontage-Outline.otf');
}

/*---nav bar---*/
h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

li {
    float: right;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: open-sans;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    color: #555555;
}

.active {
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"> 
    </head>
    
    <body>  
        
<!--nav bar-->
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="bar">
            <h1>cindy le</h1>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
                <li><a href="#work">work</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
        
    </body>



</html>
```

Comment: If you want to h1 to be in front, add a positive z-index. You are currently using -1

Answer (score 0):

Change z-index of h1 to 1

```css
html {
    margin: 0;
    background: #ffffff;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #ffffff;
}

/*---font---*/
@font-face {
    font-family: open-sans;
    src: url('open-sans.regular.ttf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Prata-Regular;
    src: url('Prata-Regular.ttf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Frontage-Outline;
    src: url('Frontage-Outline.otf');
}

/*---nav bar---*/
h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1; /* Change to 1*/
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

li {
    float: right;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: open-sans;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    color: #555555;
}

.active {
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"> 
    </head>
    
    <body>  
        
<!--nav bar-->
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="bar">
            <h1>cindy le</h1>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
                <li><a href="#work">work</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
        
    </body>



</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to fix the navbar div and then float a div to the left and include the h1 tag and a div to the right and include the ul. I wouldn't float the h1 and the ul. Something like below:

```
.navbar{
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
top: 100%;
left: 100%;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.navbar-left{
float left;
text-align: left;
}

.navbar-right{
float: right;
text-align: right;
}

.navbar ul{
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

.navbar ul li{
float: left;
}

.navbar ul li a{
display: block;
padding: 14px 16px;
color: #555555;
font-family: open-sans;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover{
color: #000;
}

.clear{
clear: both;
}  


<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-left">
        <h1>header text</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="navbar-left">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
            <li><a href="#work">work</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Sorry about formatting. Used mobile phone to post.